# SwiftUI redacted multiline text alignment

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, alignment

SwiftUI has a redacted modifier that automatically redacts the content. But seems like it doesn't work well for multiline texts:

```
Text("A large text that makes this text multiline and it should be appear centered")
    .redacted(reason: .placeholder)
    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
```

###### Unredacted:

[image: Unredacted]

###### Redacted:

[image: Redacted]

I also tried `frame` alignment and multiple different orders with no luck.

How should we fix this?

Comment: Did you ever come up with an answer for this? I am running into the same problem.